# how do I prevent github hijacking my browser back button?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey-4

I'm using firefox.

- I open a new tab
- I go to: https://github.com/git/git
- I click on the file `COPYING`
- I click the browser back button

Now I am back at an empty tab, instead of the main code page.

It is very annoying.

How can I either entirely prevent github (and other sites) overriding my browser back button, or implement a workaround when they do?

Comment: Check your configuration, I'm unable to reproduce this on FireFox or Chrome.

Comment: @0stone0 very interesting. yes, on a clean install with no extensions it doesn't happen. hmm....

Answer (score 1):

After much experimenting, I found this non-default config setting:

```
browser.navigation.requireUserInteraction = true
```

which led me to this relevant bug report:

- [Navigations from the location bar disappear from the session navigation history with browser.navigation.requireUserInteraction=true](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1644914)

I have no recollection of setting that option but resetting it to default (`false`) immediately made the location history reappear when right-clicking the back button.

---

It's slightly odd that only github was affected (but I can see they use javascript that mentions things like "poping a state from the history stack" and "prevent our state from getting out of sync with the browser's history stack", so ...).

Thanks to @0stone0 for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I've set this to prevent spam sites from loading pages into my back history preventing me from getting back to my initial search. GitHub has been the only page that has been broken since I made this change, which is very unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the back button not working, the history stack seems to be unchanged. Executing `history.go(-1)` in the console works, so I wrote a greasemonkey script to bind new hotkeys (<kbd>Shift Ctrl [</kbd>, <kbd>Shift Ctrl ]</kbd>):

```
(function(){
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.metaKey) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        
      case 219: // [
        history.go(-1);
        break;
        
      case 221: // ]
        history.go(1);
        break;
        
      default:
        break;        
    }
  }
}, false);
})();
```

Still hoping there is a way to make the back button work directly.